# Comparing class types with inheritance

Tags: java, class, inheritance

For my project, I have a HashMap with `Class<?>` as key and `MyClass` as value.

```
Map<Class<?>, MyClass> map = new HashMap<Class<?>, MyClass>();
```

As an example, I put in some values:

```
map.put(EntityDamageEvent.getClass(), new MyClass());
```

This is the inheritance tree for this key:

```
class EntityDamageByEntityEvent extends EntityDamageEvent
class EntityDamageEvent extends EntityEvent
class EntityEvent extends Event
```

The problem arises when I try to get a value from the map, but the key happens to be a subclass of the key I'm actually trying to use:

```
void doSomething() {
    EntityDamageByEntityEvent event = new EntityDamageByEntityEvent();

    post(event); //This returns null
}

MyClass post(Event event) {
    return map.get(event.getClass());
}
```

`Object.getclass()` gives me the subclass, and not the class that I want.

How should I tackle this problem? Thanks

Comment: You can use [Class.isAssignableFrom(Class<?> cls)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29).

Comment: You use inheritance but you don't want polymorphism xD nice..

Comment: @ElliottFrisch nice i didn't know about that :)

Comment: `getClass` is only ever going to give you the actual class of the actual object.

Comment: You should rethink your design. As has been pointed out, this is just the way it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys, I have done this:

```
public void post(Event event, Class<?> type) {}

this.post(new EntityDamageByEntityEvent(), EntityDamage.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the subclass ancestors, until you find someone that is in the map.

```
for (Class<T> klass = event.getClass(); klass!=null; klass=klass.getSuperclass()) {
 MyClass c = map.get(klass);
 if (c!=null) return c;
}
return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
EntityDamageByEntityEvent event = new EntityDamageByEntityEvent();
```

with

```
Event event = new Event();
```

Comment: @HotLicks ya typo my mistake. had my hierarchies backward

Answer (score 0):

A different idea:

Use the `HashMap<String, MyClass>` where the key is to be inserted with the Class's fully qualified name: `SubClass.class.getName()`. While retrieving, you can use `Class.forName(key)` to find the correct class.